# custom/DB Session in PHP/MySQL - showing ERROR in other pages

Tags: php, mysql, session

i wrote this custom session handler !
plz have a look [**and look at the below BOLD error text** to help me find out where the error is]

```
<?php
 function sess_open($sess_path, $sess_name) {
   return true;
 }

 function sess_close() {
   return true;
 }

  function sess_read($sess_id) 
{
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT Data FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $data);
 mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
 if (is_null($data))
 {
 $CurrentTime = time();
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO sessions (SessionID, DateTouched) VALUES (?,?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$sess_id,$CurrentTime);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return '';
 }
 else
 {
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE sessions SET DateTouched = ? WHERE SessionID = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$CurrentTime,$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return $sess_id;
 }
}

function sess_write($sess_id, $data) 
{
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
 $CurrentTime = time();
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE sessions SET Data = ?,DateTouched=? WHERE SessionID=?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$data,$CurrentTime,$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return true;
}

function sess_destroy($sess_id) 
{
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"DELETE FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return true;
}

function sess_gc($sess_maxlifetime) 
{
 $CurrentTime = time();
 mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM sessions WHERE DateTouched + $sess_maxlifetime < $CurrentTime;");
 return true;
}

session_set_save_handler("sess_open", "sess_close", "sess_read", "sess_write", "sess_destroy", "sess_gc");
session_start();
?>
```

this is [at above] my **DB_Session.php** file

> include 'DB_Session.php';
>   $_SESSION['foo'] = "BAR";
>   $_SESSION['bar'] = "FOO";
>   echo $_SESSION['foo']. ' '.$_SESSION['bar'];

this is [at above] my **session_start.php** file which works perfectly :)

> include 'DB_Session.php';
>   echo $_SESSION['foo'].' '.$_SESSION['bar'];
>   session_destroy();
>   echo $_SESSION['foo'].' '.$_SESSION['bar'];

this is [at above] my **session_finish.php** file which shows error :(

which gives this errors, though session is destroyed perfectly !
**Notice: Undefined index: foo in session_finish.php on line 4**
**Notice: Undefined index: bar in session_finish.php on line 4**
**Notice: Undefined index: foo in session_finish.php on line 6**
**Notice: Undefined index: bar in session_finish.php on line 6**

Table structure

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
>   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `SessionID` char(26) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `Data` text,
>   `DateTouched` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

after browsing the **session_start.php** i can see the value getting stored in the database and after browsing **session_finish.php** the value are deleted perfectly, but can not show the SESSION data in other page before destroying !

Comment: please improve this script or give any suggestion to make it better !

Comment: more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Stackoverflow got more user in quality and quantity i think than codereview.stackexchange ! So, plz dont close it ! Lot's of tags are missing in codereview.stackexchange :(

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5  now see it again !

Comment: @Sourav, yes, that's better. My vote stays ;)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 but it would be better if you can help me :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sess_read($sess_id) 
{
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT Data FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $data);
 mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
 if (is_null($data))
 {
 $CurrentTime = time();
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO sessions (SessionID, DateTouched) VALUES (?,?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$sess_id,$CurrentTime);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return '';
 }
 else
 {
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE sessions SET DateTouched = ? WHERE SessionID = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$CurrentTime,$sess_id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 return $data;    /*  $sess_id; THIS WAS CREATING PROBLEM :X */
 }
}
```

the error was returing data when the session is found !

Answer (score 0):

where is the session_finish.php file ? 
but most probably you must define your variable (foo, baz ) before you use them 
to be sure the variable is define so this notice won't appear

Comment: @hish Look at the highlighted lines, i've bolded the filename

Comment: @hish I already defined the session in session_start and then i browsed session_finish, and got those errors

Comment: there is no variable in the session (foo, baz)

Comment: @hish, nope there is. check "this is [at above] my session_start.php file which works perfectly :)"

Comment: you sure the file session_start.php execute before the file session_finish.php

Comment: it is seem there is a script make unset for this session variables before arrive to the session_finish.php file

Comment: nope, i just got 3 files there, and i've written here all the 3 files

Answer (score 0):

**DB_Session.php** is problem! Definitely.

When I remove line with custom handler `session_set_save_handler(...)` it works but with that line it doesn't. So problem is in your functions but I still can't find where?

---

**DB_Session.php**

```
<?php

 function sess_open($save_path, $session_name) {
   // my code
   global $sess_save_path;
   $sess_save_path = $save_path;
   return true;
   }

 function sess_close() {
   return true;
   }

 function sess_read($sess_id) {
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT Data FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = ?");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$sess_id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $data);
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
   if (is_null($data)) {
     $CurrentTime = time();
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO sessions (SessionID, DateTouched) VALUES (?,?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$sess_id,$CurrentTime);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     }
   else {
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE sessions SET DateTouched = ? WHERE SessionID = ?");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$CurrentTime,$sess_id);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     }
   // my code
   global $sess_save_path;
   $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_" . $sess_id;
   return (string) @file_get_contents($sess_file);
   }

 function sess_write($sess_id, $data) {
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
   $CurrentTime = time();
   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE sessions SET Data = ?,DateTouched=? WHERE SessionID=?");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$data,$CurrentTime,$sess_id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   // my code
   global $sess_save_path;
   $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_" . $sess_id;
   if ($fp = @fopen($sess_file, "w")) {
     $return = fwrite($fp, $data);
     fclose($fp);
     return $return;
     }
   else return false;
   }

 function sess_destroy($sess_id) {
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database");
   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"DELETE FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = ?");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$sess_id);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   // my code
   global $sess_save_path;
   $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_" . $sess_id;
   return(@unlink($sess_file));
   }

 function sess_gc($sess_maxlifetime) {
   $CurrentTime = time();
   mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM sessions WHERE DateTouched + $sess_maxlifetime < $CurrentTime;");
   // my code
   global $sess_save_path;
   foreach (glob("$sess_save_path/sess_*") as $filename) {
     if (filemtime($filename) + $sess_maxlifetime < time()) {
       @unlink($filename);
       }
     }
   return true;
   }

  session_set_save_handler("sess_open", "sess_close", "sess_read", "sess_write", "sess_destroy", "sess_gc");
  session_start();

?>
```

Try to replace your script with this one and let mi know what's going on there?

- Live demo for [session_start.php](http://service-kl.com/code/session/session_start.php)
- Live demo for [session_finish.php](http://service-kl.com/code/session/session_finish.php)
- Download link for all 3 scripts ([session.zip](http://service-kl.com/code/session/session.zip)).

Comment: @Sourav, how you call session_start.php and session_finish.php? Directly or from include somewhere?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5  directly ! i'm just checking if it works or not !

Comment: @Sourav, look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: the db_session should stop work if you remove session_set_save_handler(...) :(

Comment: @Sourav, yes I know.. but I have removed code related with database in testing purpose. However, I think it's something with transferring global data across your functions and now I'm trying to find what causes that annoying notice.

Comment: @Sourav, UPDATED! I can't guarantee that your database code works, but when I remove your code it works as I expected. I wrote this code according to PHP manual for [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Comment: i will tell u after giving it a try :) thnx for your help :=)

Comment: i appreciate you help bro :) but i was looking for a session with DB, your code was with file ! but still thanks for your help :) GOD BLESS

Comment: Yes, I know what are you looking for but I couldn't test it with DB. Try to adapt functions to read from and write to database like I did for file. Be aware of what each function should return as result.